# Optimizing RMI Service Response

Tags: java, rmi

I am writing a server client application, best performance is a must; I am using RMI for server-client communication, the server uses mySQL database.

Now in the client side I have a method called

```
    getLinks()
```

which invokes the same method on the server, the problem is that this method returns about 700Mb of data, which takes some time to get, and some more time to analyse.

And then I'm setting some values for each Link:

```
for (Link l : myService.getLinks()) l.setSelected(false);
```

What I have in mind right now is just getting the Link Ids first (since this would be a smaller data) and then using Asynchronous method to get each Link by Id (each link need one service call); and then setting the Link values.

Is this the best approach, is there another way of getting RMI data one by one (one method call and more than one return)?

Is there something like (yield return) in C#?

Answer (score 0):

you can also make a pagination method, which receive the initial id (or position if the id's are not a consecutive) and the length, in this way you will not send all the id's twice

Comment: please view my comment @EJP, the links are stored in a HashMap (links) which is needed all over the application.

Answer (score 0):

Are the Link objects remote objects? If not I don't really see the point of the code, as it only sets something locally in the client object which is immediately thrown away.

Assuming they are remote objects, it would be better to ship the entire update to the server and tell it to update the whole collection, something like setLinksSelected(boolean), where the server does the iteration.

But I would also be wary of updating, or even transporting, 700Mb of data via RMI whichever way you do it. That's a lot of data.

Comment: Link objects are rows in the link table in the database, and they are not thrown away; the (getLinks) method stores everything in a HasMap (links) and it is used all over the application and destroyed upon application exit. the problem is on the first call to (getLinks) since (links == null)